# Why shadows of the blades on Ingenuity navcam photos looks brighter than shadows of the legs?

Tags: mars, perseverance, photography, ingenuity

Consider this photo from the Ingenuity navcam on the first (?) flight:
[image: Shadows with different opacity]

You can see that the shadows of the blades seem brighter than the shadows of the legs. It's especially noticeable when they overlap.

It looks like the blades are kinda transparent. But that's not the case: Even if the camera works in near IR, carbon blades shouldn't be transparent.

So what is the reason?

Does Ingenuity make HDR images by combining "short-exposure" (blades look still) and "long-exposure" (blades do full revolution)?

And why does the shadow of the upper-left (on photo) blade show a gradient? (It's brighter closer to the body of the copter)

Comment: The blades are higher up off the ground than the body and legs. Light has had more opportunity to diffuse into the blades' shadows than into the shadows of the body and legs because of the greater distance. At least, that's my guess. Not sure if Martian air could be responsible for that much scattering.

Comment: @BMF: No, the Martian atmosphere is much too thin to produce such a scattering effect (and if it _was_ due to scattering, the outlines of the blades would be much more blurred). The blades must be translucent.

Comment: @TonyK translucent? Huh, that's a possibility. https://www.businessinsider.com/nasa-ingenuity-mars-helicopter-make-first-flight-on-monday-2021-4?amp I can find some images where the blades' shadows look just as dark as the body. Maybe it's somehow the motion of the blades.

Comment: @BMF: Interesting! I don't have an explanation for that. But note that the body of the helicopter has a square cross-section, whereas the solar panel is rectangular. And the OP's picture shows an opaque rectangle, which can only be shadow of the solar panel. But the solar panel is higher than the rotor blades, so it really can't be due to scattering.

Comment: @BMF: See the last three or four frames of [this video](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/26032/ingenuity-navcam/). It strikes me that 2400 rpm is _very_ fast, so it's surprising that they don't show movement blur. Perhaps the satnav camera is taking a wide-aperture, short-exposure  shot and blending it with a longer-exposure shot? I don't know why it would want to do that, but it would explain the partial shadow effect.

Comment: @TonyK oh, 2400 rpm? I honestly thought it would be faster with how thin Mars air is. That's about 40 Hz, or an Eb1 which sounds like [this](https://youtu.be/T38nCBe-U_g). It's also about the rate a racecar tire would rotate going 200 mph. I'm looking forward to an answer to this question because I'm mystified. I'm not sure, but I think I can trace the shape of the blades' shadow *underneath* the shadow of the solar panel, in certain areas. That could (not?) happen if it were double-exposed.

Comment: (okay, considering the blades are over a meter across, that is pretty darn fast)

Comment: I kind of see what you mean about the blades' shadows, but I think that is just our insatiable appetite for seeing patterns where none exist.

Comment: I think @BMF has the correct answer; if you look carefully, the shadow lightness is in order of distance from the ground; legs darkest, then body, solar panel and glades.  The difference is enough that I would guess the craft was quite close to the ground when the picture was taken.

Comment: @antlersoft I don't think I'm right. The solar panel is actually *above* the blades. Legs, body, blades, then solar panel.

Comment: The blades are angled, right? Maybe what we're seeing is light being reflected off the bottom of the blades back down on the shadowed area? The light couldn't line up perfectly with the shadow though, hmm.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127665/discussion-on-question-by-dcoder-mm-why-shadows-of-the-blades-on-ingenuity-navca).

Answer (score 5):

I believe I got the answer.

Let's check this explanation:

> it's unintentional and an artifact of how the sensor works.  Basically it still works as a much lower performance image sensor after the shutter is closed but before the stored pixel data is scanned out.  Essentially photoelectrons can still get into the storage node.
> https://mobile.twitter.com/sdamico/status/1384221915422724096

So the light leaks to the pixel during readout. In extremely low rate compared with exposure time, but exposure time is about 100us, which is 100 times smaller than 10ms of readout.

(You can estimate exposure time by the angle of smearing in blade shadow. Readout time can be estimated by maximum FPS - 100fps gives 10ms for frame)

Can we reproduce that effect?

Luckily, I found a the video where exactly same camera filming small propeller under the bright light:

[image: propeller]

You can pause video and use < > buttons to navigate frame-by-frame and observe exactly the same  translucency.

Also this post https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=267563 by the same author, shows still image of the blades with prominent translucent circle:

[image: white propeller global shutter]

Note that effect is much more prominent here. I believe thats because:

a) White propeller and dark background gives higher contrast

b) Exposure time was 4 times shorter (0x04 in the video, 0x01 in the forum post) which makes readout/exposure relation 4 times larger.

**UPD 21 Jul 2021: Infrared disclaimer**

> It seems that I was wrong assuming that Ingenuity navigation camera
> works in IR. OV7251 *can* work in IR and it's [funny little pdf](https://www.ovt.com/download/sensorpdf/146/OmniVision_OV7251.pdf)
> says about "integral 850 nm bandpass filter" (from which I was thought
> that it has only IR-vesrion). But as it turns out that there are
> different versions for IR and visible-light-only. And now I can't find
> any proofs that Ingenuity is indeed using IR version. But IR part
> still seems plausible for other cases, so I won't delete it.

I also think that effect is more prominent with infrared light, because silicon (from which sensor is made) kinda translucent in IR.

[image: silicon and IR LED]
(https://www.flickr.com/photos/imager/3380554807)

Thus make it easier to scatter around and reach storage nodes:

[image: storage node on CMOS sensor]

It can explain why amount of effect for Ingenuity and for video looks the same, despite that readout/exposure is much higher for video (I've estimate exposure in order of 10us): in video some LED was used for lighting, and LED has orders of magnitude less IR than the sun.

Comment: Beautiful! This is a really interesting answer. The cross-section drawing shows that they've included metalization over the storage area so it won't detect photons directly, but for some reason it's not sufficiently isolated to prevent a low rate of photoelectrons from elsewhere within the pixel from drifting into it during those "long" times between shuttered exposure and readout. *Cool!*

Comment: I've held double-side-polished silicon wafers in front of *thermal* IR cameras and they are as transparent as glass at those wavelengths as well as in any substnatially-longer-than-band-gap near IR. Electronics-grade, high resistivity single crystal silicon is incredibly transparent in the IR, but with an index of refraction of 2.5 to 3.5 out there there is still wicked [fresnel reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations) at each interface.

Comment: @uhoh I now think I was wrong about IR sensitivity of Ingenuity's camera (see updated answer). But I still love that scattering-idea. Gonna get global-shutter camera and test.